# How do I solve this error code in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: json, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 38, column 3: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
╷
38 │   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
│   ^
╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\Kia Com\Documents\Restaurant_App\resto\pubspec.yaml
Exited (1)

My Code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7BVv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7BVv.png)

Comment: Both images are the same, we can not see the issue.

Comment: Seems like indentation is wrong for http.

Comment: but http directly under cupertino_icons

Comment: my error      Error detected in pubspec.yaml: Error on line 38, column 3: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping. ╷ 38 │ cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 │ ^ ╵ Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\Kia Com\Documents\Restaurant_App\resto\pubspec.yaml Exited (1)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the indentation. The yaml file has strict indentation rule. Your pubspec.yaml should be like this.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

Notice the starting line of the http package. It should be one indent right of the dependencies tag and should match the indentation of flutter and cupertino_icons package.